# Почему ошибка - ORA-06502: ошибка числа или значения - во время выполнения, а не компиляции?

Tags: база-данных, oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Почему ошибка не перехватывается во время компиляции, а возникает только во время выполнения процедуры? Где логика? Или это вызвано какой-то необходимостью?

```
create or replace procedure tt is  
    a varchar2(10) :=  '-6502 - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: : character string buffer too small ошибка числа или значения'; 
begin
    null; 
end;

begin tt; end;
```

Comment: Дело в том, что при компиляции не выполняется присваивание строки переменной `a`. Попытка поместить строку в переменную `a` произойдет только запуске процедуры, по этому и ошибка выбрасывается во время запуска.

Comment: @Viktorov: То есть предполагается, что может быть динамическое формирование значения (скажем, в зависимости от параметра) и проверять в момент компиляции не имеет смысла? Или чем это может быть обусловлено, на ваш взгляд?

Comment: Не обязательно присваивать константное значение. можно при объявлении присвоить результат, возвращаемый функцией. которая вообще может брать значение из БД. И браться оно должно во время выполнения

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Объективный ответ на этот вопрос будет дать сложно, потому что [офф. документация PL/SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/) детального описания компилятоа не содержит.

---

По видимому, в вопросе ожидается поведение, как в других ЯП, например:

```
$ echo "int main() {char a[1] = {'a',0};}" | gcc -c -o a.o -x c -
<stdin>: In function ‘main’:
<stdin>:1:30: warning: excess elements in array initializer
<stdin>:1:30: note: (near initialization for ‘a’)
```

Но в данном случае, если игнорировать предупреждение, произойдёт утечка памяти.
В случае же:

```
create or replace procedure checkchr is
    val varchar2 (1) := 'ab';
begin null; end;
/
```

нарушения каких либо границ или лимитов не произойдёт.

Объявление с ограничением `(1..maxsize)` создаст переменную с так называемым *constrained data type*. Макс. длинa данных (для типа `VARCHAR2` это 32767 байт) для этой переменной при этом не изменится.
Ограничение служит для защиты от логических ошибок, которые могут появиться во время выполнения программы. Проверять на наличие логических ошибок во время компиляции, как известно, не имеет смысла.

При попытке инициализации, где будет действительно превышен установленный лимит для типа данных, компиляция конечно же завершится ошибкой:

```
create or replace procedure checknum is
    num number := 10e999;
begin null; end;
/
```

> Error(51,24): PLS-00569: numeric overflow or underflow