# Ошибка при присваивании значения переменной - ORA-06502: PL/SQL: ошибка числа или значения

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Почему в этом примере возникает ошибка?

```
set serveroutput on;
declare
    -- Запись    
    type t_recx is record (
        a varchar2(10) not null := '',
        b integer
    );
    -- Таблица записей
    type t_tbl_recx is table of t_recx index by binary_integer;
    -- Переменная
    v_recx t_tbl_recx;
begin
    -- Присваиваем значение полю записи
    v_recx(1).a := 'BBB'; -- На этой строке ошибка, хотя тип объявлен как varchar2 
    dbms_output.put_line(v_recx(1).a);
end;
```

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: ошибка числа или значения

Тип объявлен как `varchar2` и до строки с присвоением все выполняется без ошибок.

Comment: Как можно присвоить null, если поле объявлено not null  - `a varchar2(10) not null := ''`? Инициализируйте пробелом хотя бы.

Comment: Да, действительно, причина была в этом. Хотя до строки с присвоением все выполнялось без ошибок. Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Вы уже задавали похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859212/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нельзя присвоить значение `NULL` переменной объявленной  с ограничением `NOT NULL`.

> 06502, 00000, "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
>    *Cause: An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
>            occurred. For example, this error occurs **if an attempt is made to
>
>            assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL**, or if an
>            attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
>            declared NUMBER(2).

Здесь:

```
a varchar2(10) not null := '',
```

пустая строка интерпретируется как `NULL`. Тут [подробнее, почему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/805114/%d0%a0%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%83-varchar-%d0%b8-varchar2/807270#807270).

```
v_recx(1).a := 'BBB';
```

Эта строка будет скомпилирована, так как компилятор не проверяет присваиваемых значений во время компиляции. При выполнении блока, ещё до присваивания полю значения `'BBB'`, поля записи будут инициализированы, где и произойдёт попытка присвоить полю `a` с ограничением `NOT NULL` значения `NULL`.